# Pass ui slider values to php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, slider

I want to pass the value of a slider to a php variable in the same document. Although I have tried ajax from online examples it doesnt work and i cant find the solution because im new to ajax and javascript.
This is my javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery_1_1_3(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery_1_1_3( ".slider-vertical" ).slider({
      orientation: "vertical",
      range: "min",
      min: 0,
      max: 2,
      value: 0,
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        jQuery_1_1_3( "#amount" ).val( ui.value );
        jQuery_1_1_3.ajax(
        {
            type: "POST",
            url: "question.php",
            data:
            {"slider":ui.value}
        });
      }
    });
        jQuery_1_1_3( "#amount" ).val( jQuery_1_1_3( ".slider-vertical" ).slider( "value" ) );

            });
</script>
```

and i try to fetch the values with this php code:

```
if(isset($_POST['slider'])){
$vote=$_POST['slider'];
}
```

Please help me!!!!!!!!

Comment: Does it call the serverside?

Comment: how do i know if it does?

Comment: Logs on the server side for example

Comment: the slider works fine but the value doesnt send in the page even if the slider changes its value.